# GitHub - List commits by author

Tags: git, github

Is there any way on [GitHub](http://github.com/) to list all commits made by a single author, in the browser (neither locally, e.g. via `git log`, nor via the API)?

Clicking on a user name in the list of commits (Commit History) simply leads to that user's profile page. Examining the GitHub UI and searching (Google, StackOverflow) does not reveal a way to do this.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

If the author has a GitHub account, just click the author's username from anywhere in the commit history, and the commits you can see will be filtered down to those by that author:

[image: Screenshot showing where to click to filter down commits]

You can also click the 'n commits' link below their name on the repo's "contributors" page:

[image: Another screenshot]

Alternatively, you can directly append `?author=<theusername>` or `?author=<emailaddress>` to the URL. For example, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/master?author=dmethvin or https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/master?author=dave.methvin@gmail.com both give me:

[image: Screenshot with only Dave Methvin's commits]

For authors without a GitHub account, only filtering by email address will work, and you will need to manually add `?author=<emailaddress>` to the URL - the author's name will not be clickable from the commits list.

---

You can also get the list of commits by a particular author from the command line using

```
git log --author=[your git name]
```

Example:

```
git log --author=Prem
```

Comment: prem, I hope you'll forgive me commandeering your answer in the way I've done here. The (IMO ridiculous) closure of this question leaves me unable to provide the (simple) answer in any other way.

Comment: no problem Mark!! as long as it helps people, i dont mind. Anyways, thanks for latest update over the topic.

Comment: This works for some users but for other users the names are not clickable. Why?

Comment: @EdwinEvans, what happens if you try the url alternative above?

Comment: @EdwinEvans they're commit authors without GitHub accounts. I've added a note about these to the answer.

Comment: This only shows commits on that given branch. I still can't find a way to see commits by that user on any branch of the project (which is what "git log" seems to show on the cmd line). Can't believe there's no easy way to do this... as a manager it's really frustrating that I can't just say to GitHub "show me all recent commits by my employee x"

Answer (score 45):

Replace `torvalds` with Github username of the author you want.

https://github.com/search?o=desc&s=committer-date&type=Commits&q=author:torvalds

You will see all commits the author made to **all repositories** sorted by commit date descending.

Comment: Thank you. This should be the correct answer since the question does not specify per-repo commits, which all other answers make reference to.

Comment: one note: it doesn't show not merged into default repo branch commits
so if your colleаgue worked on some big feature and haven't created a PR - it will be hidden from both search and his profile ativities

Answer (score 27):

Just add `?author=<emailaddress>` or `?author=<githubUserName>` to the url when viewing the "commits" section of a repo.

Comment: This just repeats content that I added to the accepted answer over a year earlier; -1.

Comment: yeah you're right for sure - but it cuts to the chase ;-)

Comment: a little too later now, but is it possible to get all the commits of a Github user regardless of the repository?

Comment: @asgs - it appears that you can do this by going to Github's advanced search, https://github.com/search/advanced?q=test, then filling in the username you're looking for in the "From These Owners" section. Then click the tabs at the top to filter to repos, commits, etc. I randomly did one for a user, and it seems to work. [Check it out here](https://github.com/search?l=&q=test+user%3Agregorwolf&ref=advsearch&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I wish Github would provide an option to tweak the number of results per page, instead of the 10 rows they provide at the moment. Or Export as CSV would've been even better. **EDIT** - if we remove the search keyword test, it doesn't show any results; so it doesn't like we could get all the commits made by a user :/

Comment: Yeah you're right... I tried a few more approaches, but don't see any way to get it... I guess you could try doing a few searches for a single letter, then combining results... e.g. Search for "e", the most common letter in the english language ;-) I'll let you know if something else comes to mind!

Answer (score 0):

**GitHub provides this in the UI now.**

Navigate to the commit history for any branch, and then you can optionally choose the author and a date range (or switch the branch).

[image: Navigate to the history for a branch]

[image: Filter by author and date-range]