# How to see all the commits (code) by a user X in github?

Tags: github

This is somewhat embarrassing but I am not able to figure out how to see visually in browser the commits (full code) made by a user X (I am the repo owner and there are 3 contributors). I found this SO thread [GitHub - List commits by author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174276/github-list-commits-by-author) but this is not working.

I have tried to use search with author name but that is also not working. Any help ?

EDIT - Thanks, I got it, you can find it through by adding /commits?author=USER_NAME after repo url

you can close the thread now as I understand this was not very relevant to github.

Comment: You can get a list of [commits-by-author](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commits?author=markstory) via github's [contributor's graph](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/graphs) is that what you mean? If that's the question, it's off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a URL that does this by using the following formula: `http://www.github.com/PROJECT_OR_USER_NAME/REPO/commits?author=USERNAME_TO_QUERY_FOR`

Comment: Note that this will default to the master branch. As far as I can tell there's no way in GitHub to see ALL commits from the author across all branches.

Comment: @Chaulky  https://github.com/PROJECT_OR_USER_NAME/REPO/commits/BRANCH?author= USERNAME_TO_QUERY_FOR

That should do it