# Find all user commits in a github repo

Tags: github

A github repository can have commits by many users.

How can I find all commits made by a user in a github repository in browser?

Let's say
when i say https://github.com/navyad/messengerbot in browser, it shows page of that repo.

How same url can be used to figure out the commits of a user?

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: Which browser do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174276/github-list-commits-by-author

Comment: @LosManos i have updated the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If following is the repo url:

```
https://github.com/xyz/repo/
```

and you want all commits from master of user `nayad`

then

```
https://github.com/xyz/repo/commits/master?author=navyad
```

Comment: the link will give you  commits on only master...what about other branches..

Comment: and for your information , it doesn't work on github  ...atleast now in 2020