# GIT list all commits on a repo by a user

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My requirement is simple.  I just want to get all my commits on a repository in github ( basically commits by a particular user)

When I say repository ,  I mean all branches like master , dev , dev2 , dev3 etc.

Could someone throw me a light on how to get all my commits on a entire repo  either using command prompt or  GITHUB GUI .. both are fine for me.

This link doesn't answer my question .
[Find all user commits in a github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387408/find-all-user-commits-in-a-github-repo)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174276/github-list-commits-by-author

Comment: yeah.. it answers.. thanks.. I feel the GITHUB UI is bit clumsy.