# How to show all the commits by a particular author, sorted by gross changes?

Tags: git

How do I see all the commits by a particular author, sorted by gross (not net) changes? I want the output to be somewhat human-readable; something like:

```
+153 -34 abcd123 First commit
+140 -40 zyxw987 Another, smaller commit
...
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174276/github-list-commits-by-author

Comment: No, I already knew about that feature. I am looking for something *on the command-line* that will provide a *list of commits sorted by gross changes*.

Comment: By gross do you mean changes in all branches?

Comment: Git will show you the total lines added and removed for a commit. By "gross" I mean the total lines added plus the total lines removed. For example, the gross changes in `+153 -34` would be `153 + 34 = 187`.

Answer (score 3):

You could view this all through the log.

First filter by the author: `--author=[name]`
Include the `shortstat` for changes: `--shortstat`
Get the hash and subject: `--format="%h %s"`

Which outputs lines like this:

```
$ git log --author=john --shortstat --format="%h %s"
6d8ab99 some message

 14 files changed, 625 insertions(+), 78 deletions(-)
8859aa7 another message

 4 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
40f9573 stuff

 31 files changed, 461 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
0dd757c lots of stuff

 5 files changed, 42 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-)
```

Then extract and format as needed then sort. I don't know how to get there from here so I'll leave that part up to you. :)